# C# why did trace stop working

Tags: c#, nunit, trace

I have a Visual Studio solution with 2 projects. One is for the program, the other is for NUnit. I run the NUnit tests and tracing works. I can see it in the text output portion of the nunit runner. I use TraceSource, and put the stuff in a config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <!-- Different Sources to turn on or off-->
    <sources>
        <source name="MainProgram" switchName="switchAll" >
            <listeners>
                <remove name="Default"/>
                <add name="file"/>
                <add name="console"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="MainProgram.Test" switchName="switchAll" >
            <listeners>
                <remove name="Default"/>
                <add name="test"/>
                <add name="console"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <!-- Different Switches... Don't Touch-->
    <switches>
        <add name="switchAll" value="All"/>
        <add name="switchOff" value="Off"/>
    </switches>

    <!-- Different Listeners... Don't Touch-->
    <sharedListeners>
        <!-- Outputs to a Log File-->
        <add name ="test"
             type ="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="C:\test.log">
        </add>
        <!-- Outputs to a Log File-->
        <add name ="file"
             type ="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="C:\mytracelog.log">
        </add>
        <!-- Outputs to the console-->
        <add name="console"
             type ="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" >
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>

</system.diagnostics>
```

it works as desired. So i need to also test this program on a different computer. OK, simple enough. Used a batch file on this computer to Robocopy the entire project bin folder to a shared location on my network. Had another batch file that copies that folder on the shared location to the other computer's desktop.

Startup NUnit on the other computer, and nothing.. no output to Text Output... I really need that output because one of my tests if failing and I need the tracing. Biggest difference between the two computers is one is x86 win7 the other is x64 win7.

Any ideas??? I can't figure out why the tracing doesn't work.

Comment: Now that is strange.. it is now doing it on my main computer. I switched the Tools>Settings>Test Loader>Assembly Isolation to Run tests in a single seperate process. The first time I ran it Tracing worked. The second time it doesn't. Makes me think that it is loading the app.config and using that for tracing... hmmm TEST

Comment: Rats, that did not fix anything. What i am doing for right now (and I hate it) is i switched my app to a console app, and run a few of my tests via console.. which oddly enough my problem went away, so I dunno